# How to delay 'next/link' Nextjs

Tags: next.js

How add a Route link a delay for page transitions?

Nextjs Version 12.1.0

```
<Link href="/">
  <a className='logo-home'></a>
</Link>{' '}
```

the solution i used

App.js

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on("routeChangeError", (e) => setLoading(false));
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", (e) => setLoading(false));
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", (e) => setTimeout(() => {setLoading(true)}, 1000));

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeError", (e) => setLoading(false));
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", (e) => setLoading(false));
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", (e) => setTimeout(() => {setLoading(true)}, 1000));
    };
  }, [router.events]);


{loading ? (<Component {...pageProps} />) : (null)}
```

It doesn't work well.

Can someone help me. Another better solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just disable the link redirect and use router.push.

Use onClick on Link component.

```
<Link href="/" onClick={handleClick}>
  <a className='logo-home'></a>
</Link>
```

Use timeout to delay redirect.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        router.push('/');
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: I have tried it. It doesn't work as I want. I want the cloud to be able to run before switching pages. Video [link](https://imgur.com/T0NJU9H) . Source code [link](https://github.com/KenDzz/NFT-Market-Item/blob/main/components/Layout.js). Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: @KenDzz  to make the clouds work like that when you change pages, you need to put the cloud component in `_app.js`. Anything in there will survive navigations.